# If input is equal to string does not work correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, if-statement

When I input  `'*'`  it works, but with `'o'` it does not. I can't find what I am doing wrong

```
def trying():    
    player1 = input("Please pick a marker '*' or 'o' ")
    while True:
        if player1.upper() == '*':
            player2='o'
            print("You've choosen " + player1 + ". Player 2 will be " + player2)
            return player1.upper(),player2
        elif player1.upper() == 'o':
            player2='*'
            print("You've choosen " + player1 + ". Player 2 will be " + player2)
            return player1.upper(),player2
        else:
            player1 = input("Please pick a marker '*' or 'o' ")
trying()
```

Comment: why are you using .upper() ? Try without it.

Comment: hmm.. because 'o' is lower case?!

Comment: @Tibebes.M omg I missed that part.Thank you,yeah that was my mistake.I usually use lower() so I confused it

Comment: @XXDIL I am using that because in my task it is said that I need to write a code that accepts both 'O' and 'o' , I should have written lower(). My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.upper()` means, convert a lowercase letter to an uppercase, and leave everything else unchanged. That is the reason it works with `*` but not with `o`.

Replace `.upper()` with `.lower()`, and it will work!

---

```
def trying():    
    player1 = input("Please pick a marker '*' or 'o' ")
    while True:
        if player1.lower() == '*':
            player2='o'
            print("You've choosen " + player1 + ". Player 2 will be " + player2)
            return player1.upper(),player2
        elif player1.lower() == 'o': #o is lowercase
            player2='*'
            print("You've choosen " + player1 + ". Player 2 will be " + player2)
            return player1.upper(),player2
        else:
            player1 = input("Please pick a marker '*' or 'o' ")
trying()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `elif player1.upper() == 'o':` you convert the user input to uppercase and you compare it with the lowercase letter `o`.

The solution would be :

```
elif player1.lower() == 'o':
```